# Add / Remove path in different URLs in Javascript

Tags: javascript, url, path, hyperlink

I have a website that has a translation tool. I have added a pop-up  that asks the user to choose it's language in any page the user visits.

What I'm looking for is the JS code to put on each language so when it is clicked it reloads the same page with the added or removed path.

example: [www.page.com/store](http://www.page.com/store)

When the user clicks the language French he should be redirected to: [www.page.com/fr/store](http://www.page.com/fr/store)

If the user chooses English the URL remains [www.page.com/store](http://www.page.com/store) but if the user was in the French site, the code should remove the /fr path.

In the English link there should be two codes, reload the page if the user is in English or remove the /fr path if is in French.

Because the pop up is in every page, I cannot put just the link to the translated page, it needs to insert or delete the path to the URL.

I'm very new to JS so I'm having a lot of problems. Help would be appreciated.

```
 <script>
    function changePath() {
      // Get the current URL
      var currentURL = window.location.href;

      // Extract the current path from the URL
      var currentPath = window.location.pathname;

      // Modify the path
      var modifiedPath = '/fr'; // 

      // Concatenate the current path with the modified path
      var newURL = currentURL.replace(currentPath, modifiedPath);

      // Update the URL
      window.location.href = newURL;
    }
  </script>
```

I have tried this but of course the whole path is removed and changed into /fr only.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass parameter language in changePath() function and apply a condition on modified path if the path is French then go to /fr/store otherwise go to /store. In below code I pass lang as parameter and use tenary operator to check language.

```
 var modifiedPath = (lang == 'french') ? '/fr/store' : '/store'
```

I hope it will help you.

```css
        function changePath(lang) {
            // Get the current URL
            var currentURL = window.location.href;
            console.log(currentURL)
                // Extract the current path from the URL
            var currentPath = window.location.pathname;
            console.log(currentPath)
                // Modify the path
            var modifiedPath = (lang == 'french') ? '/fr/store' : '/store'

            // Concatenate the current path with the modified path
            var newURL = currentURL.replace(currentPath, modifiedPath);

            // // Update the URL
            window.location.href = newURL;
        }
        changePath('french')
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, the problem is that I need to use it sitewide, so adding the /store path means it only can work in the /store page.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a replace but just concatenate your values.

Also instead of the complete href. Just get the domain!

```js
changePath()
function changePath() {
    // Get the current hostname
    var currentURL = window.location.hostname;

    // Extract the current path from the URL
    var currentPath = window.location.pathname;

    // Modify the path
    var modifiedPath = '/fr';

    // Concatenate the current path with the modified path
    // You did a replace but your comment speaks of concatenate
    var newURL = currentURL + modifiedPath + currentPath

    // Update the URL
    //window.location.href = newURL;
    
    // Log it
    console.log(newURL)
  }
```

Comment: This almost worked, how it works is on var newURL = currentURL + modifiedPath +currentPath I needed to remove currentURL as it was giving me www.page.com/page.com/fr/store

Comment: Also, needed to remove // before window.location.href = newURL

Comment: Yeah the // was just because it didn't work on stack overflow. Also you could prefix it with the protocol but because it's the same domain, currentURL is indeed not needed.